# Video-Encoding planes

Tags: image-processing, video-processing, video

I am currently developing an Android Application for Video-Streaming. Now i came to the point where I wanted to manipulate the stream. From the API I am using I have 6 methods available for each Frame I am capturing:

`getDataY`, `getDataU`, `getDataV`, `getStrideY`, `getStrideU`, `getStrideV`

but I have absolutely no idea what the data I get from these methods represents, I also didn't find anything on Google or Bing.

Can someone explaing what the data I get from theses methods represent?

Answer (score 1):

The question might be more about code written in a specific context. However, the Y, U, V letters refer to  YUV formats, a transformation of an image in RGB format into three other planes, one of luminance, two of chrominance, that are less redundant then the red/green/blue, and are subsequently downsampled and "JPEG" compressed. A couple of links:

- [Android YUV Image format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8563523/7453794)
- [ImageFormat (Android developer forum)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat#YV12)